# URL Encode token in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Core 2 MVC. I want to generate "confirm email link ". I generate a token like so:

```
var token = await m_userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

send an email to the user to activate his/her account. however the token that comes through has removed "+" from the input:

```
    // Original
CfDJ8ON8hfMagqZNkicGHBXln5hi6kj4TCMMaxS5SaaU4BzEgFlKev1mT2gsij7gh2AkG8G+00t4n/PGwX6oQCvnpHk+wIGc1y8ycNbnzGpwW9Q8fwRlZDGQcIMtSCmX7LXwRS0iHSXgDF1O/QcDNGKbIMMZdcfMKYwnnzmUpmNxvZtG0JCYu5o754Y83VEtdbKASlzQz4aFxOUulvHRBQc3xRi2r0N8yveg26FO+RJ9khsqxKGRu4JDDVNWkpguXeVJvA==

    //Notice '+' is missin
CfDJ8ON8hfMagqZNkicGHBXln5hi6kj4TCMMaxS5SaaU4BzEgFlKev1mT2gsij7gh2AkG8G 00t4n/PGwX6oQCvnpHk wIGc1y8ycNbnzGpwW9Q8fwRlZDGQcIMtSCmX7LXwRS0iHSXgDF1O/QcDNGKbIMMZdcfMKYwnnzmUpmNxvZtG0JCYu5o754Y83VEtdbKASlzQz4aFxOUulvHRBQc3xRi2r0N8yveg26FO RJ9khsqxKGRu4JDDVNWkpguXeVJvA==
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Activate(Guid? id, string token)
{
       ...
```

What is the solution here? should I simply replace "space" with + sign?

Comment: is your token being passed by querystring? if so, this is why it is being replace with blank space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode your token and then decode when you receive the token. In this way you avoid the url encoding.

Example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var token = "CfDJ8ON8hfMagqZNkicGHBXln5hi6kj4TCMMaxS5SaaU4BzEgFlKev1mT2gsij7gh2AkG8G+00t4n/PGwX6oQCvnpHk+wIGc1y8ycNbnzGpwW9Q8fwRlZDGQcIMtSCmX7LXwRS0iHSXgDF1O/QcDNGKbIMMZdcfMKYwnnzmUpmNxvZtG0JCYu5o754Y83VEtdbKASlzQz4aFxOUulvHRBQc3xRi2r0N8yveg26FO+RJ9khsqxKGRu4JDDVNWkpguXeVJvA==";
    var newToken = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
    Console.WriteLine(newToken);
    //this will print newToken without +
    var originalToken = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(newToken);
    //this will print original token, with +
    Console.WriteLine(originalToken);
}
```